# How to use TabbedPage with MasterDetailPage with MvvmCross presenters?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am beginner in MvvmCross using it with Xmarin Forms and trying to implement a MasterDetailPage with a TabbedPage as the MvvmCross won't support the AppShell right now.

I've manage to implement what I want by myself in Xamarin Forms without using MvvmCross but when comes to implement it using MvvmCross I have no idea how to approach it.

What I'am trying to implement is something like this:

[image: FlyoutPage with TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms]

The code that works for me in XamarinForms:

In App.xaml.cs:

```
  public App()
  {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MaineMasterDetailPage());
  }
```

In MasterDetailPage:

```
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:HomePage x:Name="masterPage" BackgroundColor="Red" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>


<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <TabbedPage x:Name="tabs" android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
        <ContentPage Title="Tab1">

            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                    <Label Text="Tab1" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Tab2">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                    <Label Text="Tab2" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>


        <ContentPage Title="Tab3">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                    <Label Text="Tab3" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </TabbedPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Currently this is not possible with MvvmCross, but we manage to implement something similar using a SegmentedControl (from syncfusion or some other package, can't remember right now). We set each "tab" as a ContentView and show/hide the view when segment is selected. Side effect was that we must keep all the logic on a single viewmodel.

Comment: Well we had the option to use Syncfusion at the start of the project, but we research it and we came to the conclusion that Syncfusion controls can cause a lot of problems and add a extra layer of abstraction over MVVMCross and Xamarin.Forms so we don't use it

Comment: Also someone suggested that I can implement this overriding some MvvmCross methods, also it seems very strange that we can't use AppShell with MvvmCross ;)

Comment: I don't think they implement Shell support, basically with Shell you can replace MvvmCross, unless your projects are purely native.